# Accidentally removed console

Tags: server, grub2

I updated grub to known working settings but I guess I removed or commented the console line(s) and now my server is not booting (no ssh anyway) and I have no local console to fix it. What do I do?

Comment: What type of server?  Some virtual consoles (LOMs, iDRACs) allow for web interface console that does not rely upon the GRUB settings.

Comment: HP Microserver, it uses iLo

Comment: The virtual console shows a blank screen

Comment: If you can power cycle the server from the web interface,  you can press ESC during startup to get to the Ubuntu boot screen, and edit the line that starts Kernel by pressing the `e` key, then add on `init=/bin/bash` and you can also add on the `console=ttyS0` or `ttyS1` depending on what COM port you set it to.  Then when you are completed with that, press Ctrl+x to boot that.  It should bring to you a prompt to allow you to make all your changes as root.  You need to remount the drive as rw before you can make any changes, `mount -o remount,rw /`.  Reboot when completed

Comment: This worked! The boot screen had a timeout of 2 or 3 seconds, so I was missing it. Thank you!